# Select Frame keyword not working on Firefox but working on Chrome

Tags: selenium, robotframework

`Select Frame` keyword not working on **`Firefox`** but working on **`Chrome`**, Showing below error:

> Element with locator `'//iframe[@name='slideInFrame']'` not found.

Trying to automate same website on `Chrome` and `Firefox` browser by using `Robotframework` and `Selenium`, same script working on `Chrome` but not working on `Firefox`. Is there any solution for `Firefox`, how to select `frame` ?

Answer (score 0):

Is exactly the same code.
Can you check if your ghecko driver version is compatible with your firefox version?